# OnDispatch event in Service Constructor

Tags: php, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I have problem with attaching `OnDispatch` event in Apigility. I want to have value from custom header in constructor of my abstract Service Class. It *works* when I simply add it to on bootstrap in `Module.php`

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    $eventManager->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'onDispatch'));
}

public function onDispatch(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e){
    $e->getRequest()->getHeaders()->get('User-Token')->getFieldValue();
}
```

But I don't know how to pass this value to ServiceAbstract Constructor.

I also tried with implementing `EventManagerAwareInterface` and attaching events with `attachDefaultListeners()` method but that didn't get me any results - attached function was not called. What is the proper approach to attaching to events NOT in controllers? Thanks for any help.

Comment: From your explanation is see no real reason to have any event listeners at all; all you need to do is access the headers via the `Zend\Http\Request` instance from within a service factory. To do so you can use `$serviceLocator->get('Request')` and then inject the header value into the required service's `__construct`.

Comment: Oh, never thought of that. Yup, that is the best solution, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you have two different goals here.

**1.** Store a header variable from a route event.

**2.** Get a dependency into the constructor function of a class

### To answer 1.

You can make a listener class and attach this class to your `EventManager`. This would look something like this:

```
<?php

namespace My\Listener;

use Zend\EventManager\ListenerAggregateInterface;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Http\Headers;
use Zend\Http\Request as HttpRequest;

class MyCustomListener implements ListenerAggregateInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Zend\Stdlib\CallbackHandler[]
     */
    protected $listeners = array();

    /**
     * @param EventManagerInterface $eventManager
     */
    public function attach(EventManagerInterface $eventManager)
    {
        // attach on route
        $this->listeners[] = $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'onDispatch'));
    }

    /**
     * @param EventManagerInterface $eventManager
     */
    public function detach(EventManagerInterface $eventManager)
    {
        foreach ($this->listeners as $index => $listener) {
            if ($eventManager->detach($listener)) {
                unset($this->listeners[$index]);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Do your thing on dispatch event with your headers
     *
     * @param MvcEvent $event
     */
    public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if(!$request instanceof HttpRequest){
            // Nothing to do
            return;
        }

        $headers = $request->getHeaders();

        // You could for example get a service here and store your value
    }
}
```

You attach this listener in `Module.php` like this:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $event->getApplication();
    $application->getEventManager();
    $eventManager->attach($serviceManager->get('My\Listener\MyCustomListener'));
}
```

You have to register your listener in your `ServiceManager` either under `invokables` or `factories` with the key `My\Listener\MyCustomListener` to be able to attach it here like this.

### To answer 2:

To get a dependency in your constructor you can make a factory for your class and get the dependency from the service can provide the dependency that you need (could be from the listener from 1 directly).

```
<?php
namespace My\Factory;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use My\Folder\MyCustomClass;

class MyClassFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param  ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return Logger
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $controllerPluginManager = $serviceLocator;
        $service = $serviceManager->get(My\Service\MyStorageService);
        $dependency = $service->getDependency();
        return new MyCustomClass($dependency);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, with this I managed to accomplished my task with getting header in resourceFactory and from that it will be easy. Thanks one more time!